# Can not call navbar.js component in Home.js

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm making a clone facebook project and I am using **React js** to create my project.

I create a file called NavBar.js in a folder called Navigation and I wanna call this component in Home.js file.

But I cannot called I got this error message:

[image: Error message]

You can get a idea using these images:
[image: my files and codes]

[image: my files and codes]

I expecting the most easiest and most suitabale answer way to fix this error!

Answer (score 2):

You should rename your component and make it:

```
export default function Navbar
```

And also `import Navbar from ".../Navbar"`

Comment: But still not working

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: @Code_Sphinx_TSK do you import from "/Navigation/Navbar"? It's important to track if import is uppercase

Comment: Yes I just import

Comment: Oh finally, it worked!